# Что эффективней: inc eax или add eax,1?

Tags: ассемблер

Начал изучать ассемблер, знаю C/C++. Поэтому решил отталкиваться от знаний, которые уже есть, и начал дизассемблировать мною написанный код и смотреть как что устроено.

И сразу же наткнулся на нелогичный момент.
Если в ассемблере есть функция увеличения значения аргумента `inc eax`, то она должна отличаться от прибавления 1 к регистру путем `add eax,1`.
Я обычно предполагал, что если есть отдельные такие функции, то они эффективнее...
но если смотреть код `i++`:

```
mov eax,dword ptr [i]
add eax,1
mov dword ptr [i],eax
```

Что лучше использовать: `inc` или `add` в таком случае?

*P.S. Использую Visual Studio 2008.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, что компилятор сглупил. Вероятно сказывается тот факт, что теоретически результат i++ ещё может быть потом использовать и из-за этого он пытается сохранить результат в r\eax. На самом деле компилятор мог бы сгенерировать просто

```
inc dword ptr [i]
```

Кроме того, здесь явно целых три инструкции вместо одной и это уж точно медленнее (если только значение i++ не нужно потом).

Что же до явного сравнения add eax, 1 и inc eax, то подозреваю, что разницы в скорости никакой, но цифра 1 занимает место, а это означает, что она займёт место в очереди предвыборки кода и может сыграть отрицательную роль. А может и не сыграть.

С другой стороны, компилятор действительно упорно использует add eax, 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = atoi("7");

    return ++i;
}
```

Даёт результат без inc'а

```
00000000004004b0 <main>:
4004b0:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
4004b4:       bf bc 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005bc,%edi
4004b9:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
4004bb:       e8 e8 fe ff ff          callq  4003a8 <atoi@plt>
4004c0:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
4004c4:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
```

С другой стороны, Java JIT-компилятор использует иногда inc.. сам видел..

**UPD** 2 kiralagin: Читайте в [официальной доке Intel](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf), страница 341.

Comment: Любое действие с ++ или -- компилятор поступает одинаково:
кладет значение в eax, производит действие, записывает снова в переменную, не зависимо используется ли данная перемеренная в следующей же команде. Я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но как это процессор должен увеличить число, лежащее в памяти?

Comment: по неопытности тоже это упустил.
Вы ведь о том, что ассемблер работает только с регистрами?

Comment: Ну… по крайней мере, таковы мои представления об архитектуре процессора :). Я просто с трудом себе представляю, как он осуществляет какую-то операцию напрямую в памяти.

Comment: Я "миллион лет" ничего не писал на ассемблере, но помню что эта фича работала. Хотя, мне кажется, что всё-же я несколько ошибся, потому что адрес для inc должен быть в регистре. Но то что не само значение - это точно.

Comment: Указать прямо в лоб адрес inc-у — фигня вопрос. С лёгкостью. Вопрос в том, _как процессор это будет исполнять_. А исполнять он это будет известно как — через копирование в регистр =). Так что, говоря по-простому, мы уж точно никак не сможем ничего проиграть. Но зато гарантированно выиграем, если потом ещё нужно будет делать операции с этой переменной. Так что вывод остаётся тот же: компилятор не дурак.

Comment: Нет, проиграть мы может от использования add: мы проигрываем на перерасходе очереди предвыборки. Это можно сказать в каких-нибудь больших "вечных" циклах.

Comment: Получается при использовании inc  не устанавливается регистр переполнения типа данных?

Answer (score 5):

Всё дело в том, что вы компилируете в режиме Debug. Найдите переключатель и установите в релизный вариант)) Да, вы правы, инкремент гораздо быстрее. Просто в дебаговом варианте делается всё максимально "в лоб", дабы никто не запутался. А в релизном вы будете удивлены странностью команд (сам экспериментировал, приятно удивило). Инкремент быстрее потому что короче, меньше из памяти при выполнении читать. Это вроде основное преимущество. На то, что режим дебаговый, указывает и то, что перед изменением данные считываются из памяти, а потом записываются назад, что заметно дольше самой операции. Плюс, опыт, ибо сам когда-то столкнулся и нашёл причину;)

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Ну Вы и вопросы, конечно, задаёте! Это же всё настолько железо-зависимые вещи!

---

Общее правило простое: **в плане генерации ассемблерного кода компилятор всегда умнее (осведомлённее), чем Вы. Если он делает так, значит, так будет лучше.**

---

Вторая мысль: Вы основываетесь на ложном посыле. Введение новых машинных команд далеко не всегда диктуется эффективностью вычислений. Есть же ещё такая вещь, как эффективность программистов — согласитесь, `inc eax` написать гораздо проще, чем `add eax,1` ;). А операция крайне частая.

Теперь по поводу того, почему `add` быстрее, чем `inc`. *(Всё что я сейчас напишу не обязано являться правдой — просто мне так кажется).* Дело в том, что `inc`, в отличие от `add`, не изменяет состояние флага переноса. А некоторые другие флаги изменяет. Поскольку мне не известно ни одной архитектуры, на которой возможно выставлять флаги по одному, а не все скопом, то я пытаюсь утверждать следующее: `inc`'у потребуется сначала *считать* текущее состояние флага переноса (что порождает ложную зависимость с последующим простоем конвейера). А `add`'у это не требуется, поскольку он его перезаписывает. Отсюда и прирост производительности.

*P.S. Отказ от ответственности ещё раз: я сам в этом не очень хорошо пока разбираюсь (обращайтесь через полгодика — судя по всему, к тому времени я уже буду экспертом в этой области =) ). Просто где-то что-то подобное слышал\читал.*

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересное и на мой взгляд разумное объяснение, но надо подождать еще ответов, а то интересен факт то что i++ (часто используемая штука) не заменяется на inc eax...

Answer (score 2):

gcc (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

использует incl для i++ j++

при компиляции с -O3 он вообще держит переменные в регистрах.
gcc -S -O3

```
main ()
{
    int i = 0, j = 999;

    while (a(i)) {
      i++;
      j++;
      b(j);
    }
}
```

делает (для while) код:

```
  xorl  %esi, %esi
  movl  $999, %ebx
  jmp   L2
.p2align 4,,7
L4:
  incl  %ebx          // j++
  incl  %esi          // i++
  movl  %ebx, (%esp)  // передача j в b()
  call  _b
L2:
  movl  %esi, (%esp)  // передача i
  call  _a
  testl %eax, %eax    // проверка результата, возвращаемого в регистре eax
  jne   L4
```

По поводу скорости исполнения. Лично мне кажется, что в циклическом коде разумного размера для современной реализации архитектуры x86 скорость исполнения будет, как это ни странно на первый взгляд выглядит, одинаковой. Это связано с предвыборкой команд и их преобразованием к командам RISC-подобного ядра процессора.